# What kind of aviation careers could I pursue?

Tags: commercial-aviation, airport

I really want to be involved with airplanes and airports, but I'm not sure what the best career to go into is. I have thought a lot about air traffic control, piloting, and flight dispatching, but is there any other careers that I should think about?

Answer (score 1):

Aviation is a large field,

You can work for an Airliners manufacturer, a Military plane manufacturer, Business Jet manufacturer, Small planes, ....
You have also opportunities in the safety field, like Flight Simulator manufacturer, Authorities, .....

The question is more about what are your competencies and what do you like to do. Because flying and air traffic control are really two different kind of jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to have a precise plan to get started.

You didn't describe your age or education level, but you can probably find basic aviation classes at your local community college or flight school.  Start with some ground school, and lessons aimed at just a First Solo.   As you learn more about aviation, you'll see what appeals to you.

Some other related fields you might like are: A&P maintenance, Line Service, Aircraft Sales, Aviation Insurance, Aviation Law, Avionics.  (and probably many others)